# Extra text in title attribute of chat flag link

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

The text ".pin" or ".unpin" (based on starring) is appended to the `title` attribute of chat flag links.

[image]

Comment: Attention-to-detail'DDD!  Repeated in IE9 on Windows 7 (I only see it on starred messages though).

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 16 on Windows XP, but again, only on starred messages (resulting in `.pin`).  I only see it on chat.stackexchange.com sites (where I have moderator privileges); I don't see it on chat.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Your attention to details is over 9000!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, that one has gone unnoticed for a while. I was curious; through the magic of source control, I found a changeset from September 20th, 2010 (!), that turned

```
.attr("title", "click to " + verb)
```

into

```
.attr("title", "Flagging a message helps bring [...] abusive messages." + verb)
```

That little `+verb` was probably supposed to be removed at this point :)

(Back then, it was still possible to unflag a message, that's why `verb` contained either "flag" or "unflag". These days, the variable `verb` isn't used here anymore, but still may be used earlier in the same method, hence the seemingly unrelated "pin"/"unpin"). Aahh, the good ol' days…

Anyway, long story short: Fixed.